# Thread as member variable of class

Tags: c++, c++11, stdthread

I would like to hold a thread in a member variable of some class. The following code snippet shows what I would like to achieve:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>


class Test {

    public:
    std::thread& t;    
    Test(std::thread&& rt) : t(rt) {}    
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Test> tests;

    {
        std::thread t ([]{
            std::cout << 1;
        });
        tests.push_back(Test(std::move(t)));
    }   

    for(Test mytest : tests)
    {
        mytest.t.join();
    }

}
```

The code will break at the join() line. The error is:

```
terminate called without an active exception
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Why can't I call the thread via mytest.t when the scope of the original thread creation was left?

Comment: Your class doesn't have a `std::thread` as member, it has a _reference_ to a thread.

Comment: moreover in the for loop `mytest` is a **copy** of the elements in `tests`, not sure if thats what you want. Maybe thats what made you use a reference as member?

Comment: I see, thank you. I just can't pass the thread to the class as std::thread.

Comment: why do you want to pass it? Why not let `Test` construct the thread and only pass what the thread should execute as parameter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since std::thread are movable but not copyable, you can do like so:

```
class Test {

public:
    std::thread t;
    Test(std::thread&& rt) : t(std::move(rt)) {}
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Test> tests;

    {
        std::thread t([] {
            std::cout << 1;
        });
        tests.push_back(Test(std::move(t)));
    }

    for (Test& mytest : tests)
    {
        mytest.t.join();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

In your class you have a *reference* to a thread, not a thread object:

```
std::thread& t;
           ^
```

Which means the following sequence will happen:

```
{
    std::thread t ([]{
        std::cout << 1;
    });                                  // 1. Thread is created.
    tests.push_back(Test(std::move(t))); // 2. Reference to moved thread is taken 
                                         // and after move thread is destroyed.
                                         // 3. Now the thread is destroyed, 
                                         // but not joined which will call `std::terminate` 
                                         // (Thanks @tkausl)
}
```

If you make your class `std::thread t` the move will work.

Comment: `3. We now have a dangling reference.` We _would_ have a dangling reference in most cases. For `std::thread`s however it immediately calls `std::terminate` as the thread which gets destructed is neither joined nor detached (it is `joinable`) https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/~thread

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @tkausl that it is a reference, the `{}` destroys the thread object once it is out of scope and your reference is no longer valid. Further you need to modify your loop so that it does not create a copy of the original `Test` object. After modifications this becomes:

```
class Test {

    public:
    std::thread& t;    
    Test(std::thread&& rt) : t(rt) {}    
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Test> tests;


    std::thread t ([]{
        std::cout << 1;
    });
    tests.push_back(Test(std::move(t)));

    for(Test& mytest : tests)
    {
        mytest.t.join();
    }
}
```

Comment: once you make it a loop and add more than one `Test` to the vector, you are back to what OP has

Comment: @user463035818 absolutely, there is no mention of a loop and I did not assume. It is worth mentioning about the scope, maybe he does not know.